# Error with inserting groovy script into inline soap request

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have an error with adding groovy script into soap request. When I send:

```
<initTransferDate>${= new Date().format("YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")}</initTransferDate>
```

There is an error in response:

```
<soap:Fault>
   <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
   <faultstring>Unmarshalling Error: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2015-09-02T14:05:48.694+0300"</faultstring>
</soap:Fault>
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in a wrong format for WSDL response timezone with ":". In my case "0300" instead of "03:00". The right code is hese:

```
<initTransferDate>${= new Date().format("YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX':00'")}</initTransferDate>
```